# What means the string Route::resource('user','UserController'); in laravel?

Tags: laravel

What means exactly the following strings in laravel?:
Route::resource('user','UserController');

I have the idea is system  of routing for locate resources in laravel applications but what exactly mean every Word? **Is the word 'user' an alias for UserController?** since instead of 'user' can be used any other word

Comment: First of all you need to understand what are [RESTful Web Services](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/).

Answer (score 1):

`Route::resource` is a way to specify several routes to your controller methods with a single declaration. For example, with `Route::resource('user', 'UserController');`, you can access `index`, `update`, `create`, `show`, `store`, `edit` and `destroy` methods in your `UserController` controller as shown below:

```
GET <url>/user //points to index() method on UserController
GET <url>/user/create //points to create() method on UserController
POST <url>/user //points to store() method on UserController
POST <url>/user/{userid}/edit //points to edit(userId) method on UserController
```

Source: [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Comment: ok thanks for your answer and explanation, but then 'user' would come to be an alias for UserController since it is used for access the methods of the UserController?

Comment: @Joe 'user' is not an alias for UserController. It's the part of URL which your controllers' actions will be called throw. Do a `php artisan route:list`, then you will understand.

Comment: ok, and then that part of URL is an URI? since a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a string of characters used to identify the name of a resource. and in laravel docs says: Actions Handled By Resource Controller: Verb -Path - Action -Route Name: GET- /resource/create -create- resource.create  (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)